# Translate a web page to other language on page load

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, translation, google-translate

I am trying to convert the whole web page in different language based on the user who is logged in.
I am using the following code

```html
  <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({
        pageLanguage: 'en',
        includedLanguages: 'es',
        layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE,
        autoDisplay: true,

      }, 'google_translate_element');
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript"
          src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

This is working as expected but user has to choose the language. Is there a way I can automate this?

Also as the translate is deprecated does any body has a guide or tutorial to use the new google translate API.

Any have searched too many posts but none of them auto translate option or using the new API's

Answer (score 0):

So you would sniff the user's preferred language using [NavigatorLanguage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language) and set that as a language.

I don't know about the latest Translate API, but a quick search gave me this: https://dev.to/robertchen/how-to-use-google-translate-api-27l9

Comment: Thanks, But I already know the users preferred language.
The API link you provided is translating only a certain text. In my case I want to translate the whole web page. I was able to do that with the code above. But my issue  with that code is user needs to select the preferred language from drop down

Comment: So if it's just about activating the script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353866/how-to-force-google-translate-to-translate-the-page-after-the-script-loads