# Auto start google translation with the current browser language on page load

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-translate

I have the google translate widget on my website. I want to translate my page with the current browser language on page load. Here is my current widget code. Thanks.

```
<?php $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2); ?>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({
        pageLanguage: '<?php echo $lang;?>',`
        autoDisplay: true
      },'google_translate_element');
   }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986344/google-translate-element-load-after-page-ready

Comment: Thanks Jeroen to view my question but is not the same :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
   <div class="custom-translate" id="google_translate_element"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, autoDisplay: false},'google_translate_element');
    }

    (function() {
      var googleTranslateScript = document.createElement('script');
      googleTranslateScript.type = 'text/javascript';
      googleTranslateScript.async = true;
      googleTranslateScript.src = '//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit';
      ( document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] ).appendChild( googleTranslateScript );
    })();
    </script>
```

To know the current browser language, use the below script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var currentBLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
   console.log('Current browser lang '+currentBLang); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Vamsi but is not working. My goal is to view my web page with the same language set in the user current browser language.

Comment: Ok. To know the current browser language you can always use this below script:

`<script type="text/javascript">
  var currentBLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 
  console.log('Current browser lang '+currentBLang);
</script>`